# Bash shell in Linux Ubuntu does not launch file made executable

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a little script like this:

```
# pico db
```

2nd step:

```
egrep -i $1 <<zzzz
Debby, 275 Collins Rd., Vestal NY 13850
Cathy, 1001 N. Vermont St., Arlington, VA 22003
Scotty, 2064 N. 16th St., Arlington, VA 22001
Bill, 4000 N. Pennsylvania Ave., Washington, DC 10000
Fred, Slip 417, N. Woodward Ave., Boca Raton, FL 46002
zzzz
```

Now I saved it and made it executable with:

```
chmod +x db
```

Now when I'm trying to launch it with:

```
db deb
```

the shell just tells me:

```
db: command not found
```

But in the book 'Linux-in-24-hours.pdf' on page 127 it's written that it should work.

Did I forget something?

Pls. help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current directory is not typically in a user's `PATH`. So to run a script located in the current directory it needs to be prepended with `./` (or the full path).

```
./db deb
```